# How to make the bot react to the author's message

Tags: python, discord.py

so I'm making a discord bot and on my help command I want the bot to add a reaction to the help command message, something like this.

[image]

I've tried recreating this but it never worked, please help if you could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to [`add_reaction()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.add_reaction), you need to get the message object and specify the emoji you want to use. And because it's a [`coroutine`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines), it needs to be [`await`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#await)ed.

---

**Emoji:**

When specifying an emoji, it must be one of the following:

- Unicode - `\u2705`
- The emoji itself - ✅ (if your IDE supports it)
- The name and ID - `<:emoji_name:112233445566778899>` (for custom emojis) - `get_emoji()` also available, returns a [`discord.Emoji`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Emoji)

You can use [this](http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_emoticons.html) website to find the unicode and string representations for emojis to paste them in.
For custom emojis, you can type `\:emoji_name:` into discord and send the message, and you'll receive it in the format `<:emoji_name:123...>`.

---

**Commands:**

Thanks to `Context`, we're able to get the message via `ctx.message` when using commands:

```py
@bot.command()
async def cmd(ctx):
    # Do some stuff
    await ctx.message.add_reaction("\u2705")
```

---

**on_message():**

And we're given the `message` object itself in the `on_message` event:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.process_commands(message) # Don't forget this is you're using commands too
    if message.content.lower().startswith("!cmd"):
        # Do some stuff
        await message.add_reaction("\u2705")
```

---

**References:**

- [Coroutines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines)
- [Await](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#await)
- [Emoji finder](http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_emoticons.html)
- [`commands.Context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context)
- [`Message.add_reaction()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.add_reaction)
- [`Client.get_emoji()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_emoji)
- [`Guild.fetch_emoji()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.fetch_emoji)
- [`Bot.process_commands()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands) - "Without this coroutine, none of the commands will be triggered. If you choose to override the `on_message()` event, then you should invoke this coroutine as well."

Comment: ah thanks, but I had to change one thing and that was the "if msg.content.lower().startswith("!cmd")" line i had to change msg to message.

Comment: Oh yeah good catch haha! Good luck with the rest of your bot :^)